# Comando equivalente en Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, terminal

tengo una duda, en windows utilizo mucho un comando que me permite ubicarme dentro de un directorio y crear un archivo de texto con todos los archivos existente en el directorio en cuestion el comando que he utilizado para ello es el siguiente

```
cd /carpeta/ruta_de_archivos
copy *.* salida.txt
```

si en mi ruta hay 5 o 200 archivos .prn o txt el comando que utilizo simplemente crea un archivo de nombre salida.txt con el contenido consecutivo de mis archivos,
 Recien he volado Windows y he instalado al 100% Xubuntu pero no se como puedo hacer lo que antes hacia desde windows como yo lo indique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta involucra tres puntos:

- El comando [`cat`](http://www.linfo.org/cat.html) que te permite "concatenar" uno o más archivos
- La expansión de comodines de `bash`
- Y la redirección mediante `>` de una salida a un archivo

Algo así:

```
cat *.* > salida.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro que el comando `cat` acepte *wildcards*, así que la ruta segura, para mi, sería:

```
cd /ruta/de/archivos
rm salida.txt
for file in *; do cat $file >> salida.txt; done
```

de esta manera, el interprete de comandos es el encargado de hacer la iteración por todos los archivos.